# linker error - cross compile for Beaglebone Black on Debian (Jessie) using Eclipse 3.8.1

Tags: eclipse, gcc, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, newlib

I am trying to get a basic cross compiler for the BeagleBone Black setup.
I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://michaelhleonard.com/cross-compile-for-beaglebone-black/) but ran into some snags...
When dowloading the toolchain for the arm platform the tutorial showed the "gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi" as a package for Ubunto so I figutred there would be one for Debian... No dice, the closest I could find is the "arm-none-eabi" package. Being new to this I gave it a shot.

I made a simpe "Hello World" application as the tutorial suggested and it compiles under the standard tools. Under the cross tools however, I add the prefix `amr-none-eabi-` and the path `/usr/bin/` the following is the result of the build.

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/test.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
arm-none-eabi-g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.d" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/test.cpp

Building target: test
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++  -o "test"  ./src/test.o   
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/stdlib/../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:70: undefined reference to `_exit'
makefile:45: recipe for target 'test' failed
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/stdlib/../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:63: undefined reference to `_exit'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/fstatr.c:62: undefined reference to `_fstat'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-openr.o): In function `_open_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/openr.c:59: undefined reference to `_open'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:58: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:61: undefined reference to `_kill'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:96: undefined reference to `_getpid'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/writer.c:58: undefined reference to `_write'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/closer.c:53: undefined reference to `_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/isattyr.c:58: undefined reference to `_isatty'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/lseekr.c:58: undefined reference to `_lseek'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
/home/tin/projects/debian/arm-toolchain/collab-maint/newlib/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/readr.c:58: undefined reference to `_read'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1

18:18:55 Build Finished (took 564ms)`
```

I can't seem to find anyhting that works to remove these errors. I would greatly appreciate any guidence I can get on this. I'm using Debian 8.1.0 and it is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and my mistake was to use the wrong toolchain...

Linaro makes a [toolchain](http://releases.linaro.org/14.11/components/toolchain/binaries/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-4.9-2014.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz) for the hard float arm architecture.

Simply get the linked archive, extract it, and point eclipse in the right direction. I've now got eclipse to proerly build programs for the beaglebone. I've also got eclipse to properly connect to the remote application on the BBB.

Cheers,